# difference between Authorize Credit Card and Charge Credit Card in authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net

I am working on a website where I want to add payment option using authorize.net, I am new in authorize.net and have some doubts.

What is the difference between Authorize Credit Card and Charge Credit Card in authorize.net?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Charge Credit card method is used to authorize and capture a credit card payment whereas authorize credit card is used to authorize a credit card payment. To actually charge the funds you will need to follow up with a capture transaction.

The authorize method is done post the payment as to check if the payment is successful, normally its between the credit card issuing bank and the seller.

To understand various methods  check the developer apis or the credit card payment lifecycle.
http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/#payment-transactions-authorize-a-credit-card

Comment: so, should I use charge credit card only and it will automatically authorize card as well?

Comment: It depends on your use case how you want to process the payment. Authorization  transaction type is sent for authorization only. The transaction will not be sent for settlement until the credit card transaction type Prior Authorization and Capture, or the transaction is submitted for capture manually in the Merchant Interface.  More info is available at http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/payment_transactions.html